# hide certain options based on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select list whereby each option is generated with a unique value. I have no control overt this part of the html but is there any way I can hide certain options form the list by using their unique values?

```
<select name="manufacturer">
    <option value="any">Any Manufacturer</option>
    <option value="38">Aerial</option>
    <option value="31">BlueLift</option>
    <option value="33">Braviisol</option>
    <option value="57">Genie</option>
    <option value="52">JCB</option>
    <option value="56">JLG</option>
    <option value="53">Manitou</option>
    <option value="54">Skyjack</option>
    <option value="55">Toucan</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What values do you want to hide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
 $('select[name=manufacturer] option[value=smvalue]').hide();
```

replace smvalue with option value you wanted to hide.

Comment: Same with CSS btw... `select[name=manufacturer] option[value=54]{display:none}`

Comment: Thanks very much Milind, and to everyone who posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by using an `attribute selector`,

```
$('select[name="manufacturer"] option[value="SomeValue"]').hide();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5gvyZ/)

Comment: `options` i think this should be `option` slice the **s**.

Comment: @Jai yeah, i just noted that typo, while building a demo.. anyway thanks.. :)

Comment: your demo works? I mean I can still find value which u suppose to hide

Comment: @Neel try to search for an option "JLG". You would not find it. :)

Comment: JLG is there bro that is why I am saying

Comment: @Neel I am damn sure, fiddle wont display that option. what browser are you using..?

Comment: according to you JLG should not be in dropdown list right? im using IE11

Answer (score 1):

Or if you need to hide with multiple values:

```
$('select[name="manufacturer"] option[value]').filter('[value="52"],[value="54"]').hide();
```

Use `filter` on all options. This for example will hide "JCB" and "Skyjack" options.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('[name=manufacturer]').find('option[value="yourvalue"]').hide();
```

replace yourvalue with option value you wants to hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery filter [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V75HC/)

```
var removeList = ["38", "31", "33", "57"];
$('select[name="manufacturer"] option').filter(function(){ 
    return removeList.indexOf(this.value) != -1;
}).hide();
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted! What's wrong with this answer?